# Correct notation of function with given property

Tags: functions, notation

I require a function with the following property:

$$
  f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \ge 0 \\ 0 & x \lt 0 \end{cases}
$$

This function will be used within an integral, e.g.

$$
  \int_0^T f(a(t)-b(t)) dt
$$

I wonder if such a function exists. Is my notation correct or is there a more common way to express the function?

Comment: What you have written completely determines the function. There is no need to express it in any other way.

Comment: @Did indeed, what was I thinking of. It's $x*H(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^+\quad\text{(positive part)}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: Is this enough without further explanation? $\int (a(t)-b(t))^+ dt$

Comment: Depends on the readership. You might want to add "where, for every real number $x$, $x^+$ is the positive part of $x$" the first time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a case free definition for $f$, take 
$$
f(x)=\frac{x+|x|}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

One more:
$$f(x)=\max(x,0){}{}{}{}$$